# Isotropic points with a jacobian matrix

Tags: matrix-calculus

As definition, in order to find the isotropic points of a jacobian matrix, the matrix's columns become orthogonal and equal to the magnitude. I don't quite understand this definition. if i have a matrix looks like this:

```
a   b
c   d
```

Matrix example:

```
2.x     0
2.y+3   3
```

How can I find its isotropic points ? 

 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The columns must be orthogonal to each other (i.e., the dot product of any two columns must be equal to $0$), and their vector norms must be equal. For the general $2\times 2$ matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a &  b \\
c &  d
\end{pmatrix}
$$
these requirements amount to: $ab+cd=0$, $a^2+c^2=b^2+d^2$.

For the concrete example
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2x   &  0 \\
2y+3  & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
the above requirements simplify to $2y+3=0$; $(2x)^2+(2y+3)^2 = 9$. Hence $y=-3/2$ and $x=\pm 3/2$.